# Javascript - is it possible to create a new element then transfer the id of an active element to the new element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I made a gradient sandbox program with JS/HTML/CSS, basically to practice dom manipulation.  So far, I have a working program where I can move a box around the screen with the arrow keys, change it's heighth, width, border radius, and colors.  I would like to be able for the program to create a new box and then pass the ID attribute of the old box to the new box, so the user will be able to do the same manipulations with the new box, while the old box sits on the screen with the user changes in place.  So far, trying to pass the id to the new box has just made the program crash.

This code activates on "n".  it does create a new box, but the new box can not be manipulated, and the old box does not retain it's changes, and the background color of the program messes up:

```
function newBox(event) {
  box.style.border = "none";
  box.id = ""
  let box2 = document.createElement("div");
  body.appendChild(box2);
  box2.id = "box";
}
```

The beginning of the program contains the line:

```
let box = document.getElementById('box')
```

and the `box` variable is what gets manipulated by keydown events.
I also tried assigning a global counter variable `i` and changed the above line to:

```
 let box = document.getElementById('box' + i.toString() )
```

the `newBox()` function would increment the counter and assign the new box an id of `('box' + i.toString())`. This also caused the program to crash.

Thanks for looking at the problem.  I'm very new to coding, so I'll take *"What you're trying to do is completely impossible"* as a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Please show us more of the relevant code, preferably as a runnable snippet, in particular how are you saving the new settings for a moved box? Are you updating its style attribute? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your event listeners are all bound to the `box` element and won't be registered on `box2` after you have added it. To manipulate your box you don't actually need the ID, you just need to store the reference to the last box you created.
In my example I still set the ID, as that was part of your question. Whenever "n" is typed on the keyboard, a possible old box will have its ID set to blank (you might want to remove the ID altogether, using [removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)), a new element will be created with the given "#box" ID, which will then be movable via cursor.

```js
let box;

function newBox() {
  if (box) {
    box.style.border = "none";
    box.id = ""
  }
  let box2 = document.createElement("div");
  box2.classList.add("box");
  document.body.appendChild(box2);
  box2.id = "box";
  box = box2;
}

function moveBox(x,y) {
  if (box) {
    box.style.top = parseFloat(box.style.top || 0) + y + 'px'; 
    box.style.left = parseFloat(box.style.left || 0) + x + 'px'; 
  }
}

document.onkeydown=function(event) {
  switch (event.key.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'n':
      newBox();  
      break;
    case 'arrowleft':
      moveBox(-1, 0);
      break;
    case 'arrowright':
      moveBox(1, 0);
      break;      
    case 'arrowdown':
      moveBox(0, 1);
      break;
    case 'arrowup':
      moveBox(0, -1);
      break;      
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px Calibri, sans-serif, normal;
}
#box {
  background-color: red;
}
.box {
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
Type "n" to create a new box and to move it.
```

Comment: With your suggestions, I fixed the program.  reassigning box to box2 was key, and then I had to copy several lines of code from the beginning of the program into the newBox() function to reset the properties of 'box'.  It works great now!  Thank you!

Comment: That sounds great! Then all the best for your practice and enjoy getting better day after day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an **"ID"** use **"Class"**. Also, you could use JS to create an **"Object / Template"** of your **"Box"** element to help differentiate between new instances of your box element. Create a **"Method"** for your box **"Object"** where it removes the event listener when creating a new instance. You could store these Object instances in an **"Array"** for easier **"Indexing"**.

*Hopefully that isn't confusing. I tried to give you keywords that I believe would help get you in the right direction.*

[MDN - Remove Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

```js
class Box {
  constructor(height, width, color, posX, posY) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.color = color;
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
  }
}

let arr = [];

function newBox() {
  let box = new Box(10, 10, 'blue', 50, 50);
  arr.push(box);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newBox()">
Box Gen
</button>
```

Comment: Although this has some ideas about how to save info on various elements, I don't understand why using class as opposed to id is correct in this circumstance (since by definition only one element is changeable at a time) and I don't understand how you are saving the user-changed dimensions/color etc.

Comment: @AHaworth - Usually **ID** is reserved for **unique** elements. Aside from this convention I'd advise OP to use **Class** because he wants to create a new instance of the original box with the same manipulation methods while also keeping the original box with its own properties. Doing so in this manner would allow OP to go back to previous boxes an continue moving them by accessing each box/object within the array where they've been stored.

It would be worthwhile for OP to post a snippet of his program to better understand the desired outcome.